# Hashchange not firing when user clicks on same link

Tags: javascript, browser-history, hashchange

I'm creating an HTML and Javascript client for running in browser which talks to REST API. I'm using [RouteMap](https://github.com/OpenGamma/RouteMap) to set my URLs. So I've kept a convention something like this

```
http://mysite.com/#/{ResourceName}/[edit|view|list]/[Id]/
```

I've set just one route and I'm grabbing these parameters in the function bounded to hashchange. Most of the things work fine. Just two issues and I'm stuck because of them.

1. If the user clicks on the same link twice, hashchange event doesn't fire. Yes, hash has not changed so obviously it won't fire. But there should be something which can be done and I'm missing that.
2. If I change something in the UI (like bring up new divs and hide some) for which I don't want to change the hash link, I loose that history and can't go back by clicking the back button properly.

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

For #1, you probably want to attach a handler to the link click event. That way you can tell if the link is being clicked. When I use onhashchange, I always attach something to the click event to assist polyfills for onhashchange, so at least I can tell when it's failing.

For #2, I want to point out that having automatic stuff change the user's history is problematic. You could fill someone's history with minute, meaningless hash changes. I recommend only changing the history when the user actually interacts. Short of that, HTML5 does offer `pushState` and `popState`. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)