# How to detect redirection to the same address when using hash navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, browser

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307241/jquery-or-js-detect-when-hit-enter-on-same-hashcode-url-on-address-bar) is sort of what i'm thinking, but has no answers.

I have successfully implemented hash navigation in my application using the following code:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    loadContent(location.hash.slice(1));
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

I use this event to download partial HTML content from the server via Ajax, and it gets called when the browser detects a change on the hash in the address bar. The addresses looks like this:

https://www.mywebsite.com/#/account/login

The problem is, when the link is the same it does not fire the hashchange event (for obvious reasons). I need to call the function `loadContent` to refresh the page.

For example, before I implemented hash navigation, if the user wanted to discard all the changes he made to the page, he simply clicks the same link in the system menu, or click the address bar and hit enter. Then, the browser will redirect to the same page and drop all the changes.

But now, I can't detect that. What can I do to detect those commands and call my `loadContent(location.hash.slice(1));` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I come to conclusion that there's no way to do that. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642225/hashchange-not-firing-when-user-clicks-on-same-link) that is very close to mine, but also no useful answer, other than handling the "onclick" event on every link on the site. Not a very beautiful solution - and does not solve the functionality of hitting enter on the address bar.

I ended up with a different approach. Definitely does not solve the way I wanted, however I think that it's more elegant from code perspective and practical from user perspective. I created a keyboard shortcut to refresh the page:

```
function doc_keyUp(e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 82) {  // ALT + R
        if (confirm("Discard changes and refresh the page?")) {
            loadContent(location.hash.slice(1));
        }
        return false;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', doc_keyUp, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may a simple approach, but what if you store your current hash in a property and afterwards register a click event and check if the hash is still the same?

Here is an (untested) example. But you should get the idea.

```
var storedHash = document.location.hash;

// You may add a data attribute to corresponding links to not 
// catch all 'a'-tags (i.e. document.querySelectorAll('a[data-nav=true]'))
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

for (var i in links) {

    if (!links.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
         continue;
    }

    links[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (document.location.hash === storedHash) {
            // Here comes your logic
        }
    }); 

}
```